# How to use like with whereIn in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

i am using laravel 8 and want use like query with whereIn.
it's my query:

```
       $details = explode(" ", $request->detail);
        $doctors->whereIn('specialities.title', 'like', '%' . $details . '%')
            ->orWhereIn('users.first_name','like',$details."%")
        ->orWhere('users.last_name','like',$details."%");
```

but i get errors:
{message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…}

exception: "ErrorException"
line: 39
message: "Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my logic and it work for me and return correct result:
because i am searching records from multiple fields

```
$details = explode(" ", $request->detail);
        $doctors->where('specialities.title', 'like', '%' . $details[0]. '%')
            ->orWhere('users.first_name','like',count($details) > 1 ? $details[0] : 
         $request->detail ."%")
            ->orWhere('users.last_name','like',count($details) > 1 ? $details[1] : 
           $request->detail ."%");
```

Comment: great solution it worked for me also

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `whereIn` expect two parameter one is column name and second one is the `array` of data and in you case second parameter is `like` which is a string.

You can do it like this:

```
$details = explode(" ", $request->detail);
        $doctors->where(function ($query) use($details) {
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($details); $i++){
            $query->orWhere('specialities.title', 'like',  '%' . $details[$i] .'%');
         }      
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use($details) {
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($details); $i++){
            $query->orWhere('users.first_name, 'like',  '%' . $details[$i] .'%');
         }      
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use($details) {
         for ($i = 0; $i < count($details); $i++){
            $query->orwhere('users.last_name', 'like',  '%' . $details[$i] .'%');
         }      
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i tried your code but get error:

message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
line: 45
message: "Array to string conversion"

Comment: You are getting the error because you need to change the whereIn implementation in other two where loop as well. i had implemented for  one loop only